# Do not show hats to people who haven't visited the site

Tags: feature-request, winter-bash-2015, winter-bash

I have seen [a user](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/32004/user15964) who has not visited the site since Winter Bash has started, and still, his avatar shows a hat. In my opinion, this is at least disrespectful to them.

Therefore I suggest that hats are shown only after the user has visited the site during the Winter Bash season.

Answer (score 13):

The only way a user can wear a hat is if they explicitly put it on from somewhere. When they go to don their chapeau they are also given the option to only show it on the site they are putting it on from:

[image: only on this site]

So users already have the ability to restrict the sites which show their capped avatars.

Answer (score 10):

The avatar can only wear a hat if the user has chosen one.

The only explanation is that the user only opened his profile page on Tex and picked a hat to wear. Opening the user profile doesn't count on your days active, so that would explain why he doesn't seem active, while he was.

Also, the hat can be derived from another site, since hats can be shared across the network. Why wouldn't you be able to share the hat across the network? A hat doesn't indicate activity on that site, so why bother?